# How could i receive a child class as a parameter where a parent class is expected, yet not allow the user to instantiate the parent class?

Tags: java, class, encapsulation

i'm new to java programming, and i'd like some help figuring this out, here's this code to illustrate my question, i have a parent class `Person`, of which i create 3 child classes, `Player`, `Arbiter` and `Trainer`, and then i can pass any of those 3 classes as parameter to another class, `Game`, by expecting a `Person` class object

```
public class Game {

    private Person member;

    public Game (Person member){
        this.member = new Person();
        this.member = member;
    }
}
```

My question is, aside from making multiple constructors, how could you achieve a similar result while making the parent class abstract to disallow the user from creating instances of it, and thus achieve more encapsulation?

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me. You want to disallow the user to create `Game`-objects? If so, a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) might be fitting. --- The parameter on your constructor seems superfluous, since you do not use it.

Comment: @Turing85 Sorry, i was just trying to keep it as simple as possible, i want to disallow the user to create `Person` class objects, while also being able to use them in order to receive as a parameter any of the 3 child classes which extend from it.

Comment: Can the user instantiate new instances of those child classes?

Comment: Yes, i want the user to be able to create instances of the child classes, to use in the `Game` class, yet not allow them to make an instance of the `Person` class outside of the constructor for `Game`

Comment: Rewrite the constructor of `Game` to `public Game (Person member){ this.member = member; }` and set the constructor of `Person` to `protected`. You can already pass all subclasses to the constructor. You can read more about access modifiers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i feel pretty dumb not realizing i could just make the constructor protected, haha.

Comment: Make the `Person` constructor protected or private, or make the class `abstract`. The first line of your `Game` constructor is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

make your `Person` class abstract.

You can read more about what this means here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

But the basic point is that abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.